# Can a controller be tasked to provide more than one ATC service at a time?

Tags: air-traffic-control, icao-sarps

During a visit to one of the ATC Facility  I found out that the Aerodrome Controller was also providing procedural approach control service along with aerodrome control service.

Similarly, Area Radar Controller of the same facility was also permitted to assume the responsibility of Procedural (Non Radar) controller (who acts as a backup to the Radar Controller) in the absence of Non Radar controller to provide relief to him.

I find both of these arrangements a violation of safety. I tried to find some reference to support my idea about this in the ICAO DOC 9426 (ATS Planing Manual) and Human factors Training in ATM, but could not find out anything that specifically prevents or allows this particular arrangement.

Can these services be combined? Any reference to the ICAO doc or some regulation would be a great help.

Comment: There are established procedures for combining positions during light workloads. At my field ground/clearance delivery and tower are frequently the same person during slow times. Likewise, when flying cross-country I might have 10 different controllers on a weekday flight into the LA area, but only four or five on a Sunday morning or late evening. It’s perfectly normal and not a safety risk.

Comment: *I find both of these arrangements a violation of safety.*  Please describe your qualifications and credentials to make such a determination.

Comment: "I find both of these arrangements a violation of safety" On the contrary, controllers generally make more mistakes during quiet periods with very little traffic, so combining sectors to keep us moderately busy will actually increase safety, from a human factors perspective.

Answer (score 5):

Since you've asked for a document, check [ICAO Doc 4444](https://www.google.com/search?q=icao%20doc%204444):

> 3.1.3.1 Where traffic demand varies significantly on a daily or periodic basis, facilities and procedures should be implemented to vary the number of operational sectors or working positions to meet the prevailing and anticipated demand. Applicable procedures should be contained in local instructions.

The ATS authority *can indeed* vary the number of working positions based on demand. The local instructions of the airport you visited will contain the details you need.

Answer (score 4):

JScarry is right.  Workload dependent, its completely acceptable for an ATC employee to provide multiple services.  No need to have 1 on Clearance, 1 on Ground, and 1 on Tower if you service 5 aircraft an hour.

Answer (score 1):

It is a routine occurrence at ATC facilities to combine separate functions(e.g. Radar Controller, Hand-Off Controller) as well as different positions or sectors as the traffic conditions warrant.